# Extract text using AWK command into multiple column

Tags: shell, awk

I have below text:

```
    roledetails="name: CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN
    description: Basis Admin
    readOnly: <null>
    roleReferences:
      - description: desc1
        name: AuthGroup_Administrator
        roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
        roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_Administrator
      - description: Desc2
        name: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
        roleTemplateAppId: it!b2455
        roleTemplateName: AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
"
```

I like to convert into .csv file in below format. How will I do it by using AWK ? Note: Desc field has value which may have comma in text so to avoid .csv file conflict, replace comma in Desc field with ":" Colon.

```
Collection Role, Desc,Role_Name,App_Id, Role_Template
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN, desc1, AuthGroup_Administrator,it!b2455,AuthGroup_Administrator
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN, desc2, AuthGroup_BusinessExpert,it!b2455,AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
```

I tried below code but not working:

```
declare fullfilepath=$(pwd)"/test1.csv"    
awk -F':[[:space:]]+' -v fullfilepath="$fullfilepath" 'NR==1{               # When on Line 1
        a=$2;cnt=0            # Set a and cnt vars
    }
    /^-/{                     # When line starts with -
        rta[cnt]=$2; getline; # Add role template app ID to rta array
        rtn[cnt]=$2; getline; # Add role template name to rtn array
        n[cnt]=$2;cnt++       # Add name to n array
    }
    END{                      # When the file processing is over
        for(i=0;i<cnt;i++) {  # Iterate over the found values and... 
            #print a","n[i]","rtn[i]","rta[i]     # print them
            printf a","n[i]","rtn[i]","rta[i] "\n"  >> fullfilepath   # print them
        }
    }' <<< "$roledetails"
```

Comment: Is it YAML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- header should have 5 fields instead of the 4 provided by OP
- data fields should not have spaces before/after the comma (as in some of OP's expected output fields)
- each `rollReferences` block has the same 5 fields and the last field is always `roleTemplateName`

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN                      { FS  = ":[[:space:]]+"
                             OFS = ","
                             print "Collection","Role Desc","Role_Name","App_Id","Role_Template"
                           }
$1 ~ /^name$/              { coll = $2 }
$1 ~ /- description$/      { desc = $2 }
$1 ~ / name$/              { name = $2 }
$1 ~ / roleTemplateAppId$/ { id   = $2 }
$1 ~ / roleTemplateName$/  { print coll,desc,name,id,$2 }
' <<< "${roledetails}"
```

**NOTE:** this is heavily dependent on the exact format of the input data

This generates:

```
Collection,Role Desc,Role_Name,App_Id,Role_Template
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN,desc1,AuthGroup_Administrator,it!b2455,AuthGroup_Administrator
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN,Desc2,AuthGroup_BusinessExpert,it!b2455,AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
```

Comment: How do I write to file ? $fullfilepath

Comment: @LordOfTheRing you can redirect the entire set of `awk` output to your output file, eg, change the last line to `' <<< "${roledetails}" > "${fullfilepath}"`

Comment: Thanks. How do I replace "," with ":" in description field to avoid csv getting incorrect column ?

Comment: @LordOfTheRing are you implying each line should have 4 fields and the first (data) field is `CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN, desc1` (instead of `CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN`)?  if this is the case then please update the question with these additional details *AND* make sure you update question to show the expected output with this 'new' format requirement

Comment: In some description field text have comma (,) in text and when I write in csv file, it is changing format so I am trying to replace comma with some other character so csv file column does not get messed up.

Comment: @LordOfTheRing  if it's just the **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator (aka delmiter) that needs changed then change `OFS=","` to `OFS=";"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255130/discussion-between-lord-ofthering-and-markp-fuso).

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr)

```
Collection,Role Desc,Role_Name,App_Id, Role_Template
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN,desc1,AuthGroup_Administrator,it!b2455,AuthGroup_Administrator
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN,Desc2,AuthGroup_BusinessExpert,it!b2455,AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
```

From variable using Bash `<<<` redirection:

```
$ role_details="$(cat roledeets)"
$ txr rd2csv.txr <<<"$role_details"
Collection,Role Desc,Role_Name,App_Id, Role_Template
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN,desc1,AuthGroup_Administrator,it!b2455,AuthGroup_Administrator
CLD:HYB_Y_BASIS_ADMIN,Desc2,AuthGroup_BusinessExpert,it!b2455,AuthGroup_BusinessExpert
```

Code:

```
name: @coll
@(collect)
      - description: @desc
        name: @name
        roleTemplateAppId: @appid
        roleTemplateName: @templ
@(end)
@(output)
Collection,Role Desc,Role_Name,App_Id, Role_Template
@  (repeat)
@coll,@desc,@name,@appid,@templ
@  (end)
@(end)
```